# Compare two giant dataframes

Tags: pandas, loops, dataframe, compare

I have two giant dataframes, one has 38k rows and the other 42k.  I am trying to put together a code that compares these two df and isolates unique rows that don't exit in the other.  I tried nested loops, but the amount of data is just too much and takes forever to finish.  I am looking for a simpler and more efficient way to do this job. Here is the situation:
Df1 has the following important columns: Business_unit, operating_unit, Process_num, Res_type.
Df2 has similar columns but named differently. For instance, Business_unit is now Unit.  Operating_unit is now Oper Unit. 
Also, the datatype for these columns are different across the two tables.  For instance Business Unit is 01 (str) in one table, but 1 (int) in the other.  So if I were to use concat then remove duplicates, I would have to make the two tables into the same format.  How should I go about to do this?  I am currently using the following nested loop, but this can only handle about 1000 rows.  Anything beyond that would take forever to run.

```
match_count=0
for index, row_a in SQL_download.head(n=1000).iterrows():
    for index, row_b in web_pull.head(n=1000).iterrows():
        if int(row_a['Process_Number'])==row_b['Process'] and int(row_a['Resource_Type'])==row_b['Res Type'] and row_a['Amount']==row_b['Sum Amount'] \
        and int(row_a['BUSINESS_UNIT'])==row_b['Unit'] and int(row_a['OPERATING_UNIT'])==row_b['Oper Unit'] and int(row_a['ACCOUNT'])==row_b['Account']:
            findmatch=True
            match_count=match_count+1
            break
```

Comment: `concat` then filter by `~df.duplicated(keep=False)`. You should provide a [mcve] so that someone can provide an answer to your problem. Otherwise there are far too many assumptions to be made.

Comment: The two tables are identical but not exactly the same.  So I need make them conform to the same set of format and datatype before I can eliminate duplicates, correct?

Comment: Any issue with what I propose bellow ? If so, please comment, else please upvote.

Comment: @Setop, I like your method.  However there are several issues with it.  1. I need filter on several columns, not just one single column.  2. my two tables are identical but not exactly the same. Say business unit 01 in one table is just an integer 1 in the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine merging and filtering :

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [0, 1], 'col_left': ['a', 'b']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 2], 'col_right': [2, 2, 2]})

df3 = df1.merge(df2, on="col1", how="outer", indicator=True)

df3[df3._merge != "both"]
```

produces :

```
   col1 col_left  col_right      _merge
0     0        a        NaN   left_only
2     2      NaN        2.0  right_only
3     2      NaN        2.0  right_only
```